# Java doesn't recognize Wi-Fi Broadcast address

Tags: java, network-programming, wifi

Alright, so I adapted the code from http://enigma2eureka.blogspot.com/2009/08/finding-your-ip-v4-broadcast-address.html in an attempt to find the IP address of the Broadcast Address on my Wi-Fi Router.

```
protected static InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = interfaces.nextElement();
            System.out.println(networkInterface.toString() + networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses());
            if (networkInterface.isLoopback())
                continue; // Don't want to broadcast to the loopback interface
            for (InterfaceAddress interfaceAddress : networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
                InetAddress broadcast = interfaceAddress.getBroadcast();
                if (broadcast == null)
                    continue;
                return broadcast;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However, it prints the following - the name and the list of interface addresses:

```
name:lo (Software Loopback Interface 1)[/127.0.0.1/8 [/127.255.255.255]]
name:eth0 (Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter)[]
name:net0 (Belkin USB Wireless Adaptor)[null]
...
```

The Belkin adapter - net0 - seems to have a null broadcast address, although it shouldn't. (I did remember to set the prefer IPv4 system property) Can anyone identify why it returns null?